# How to replace the binary column (1,0) to (0,1) based on value_counts in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas dataframe column I get a value_counts() as

```
Data['Gender'].value_counts()
Out[98]: 
1    169325
0     21289
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

I am not sure how to swap 1 to 0 and 0 to 1, if value_counts() of 1 is > 0, say from the output 1 is 169325 which is greater than 0 which is 21289, if its reverse no swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the `value_counts` is bit of over kill and we just using `mean` here

```
Data['Gender'].mean()>0.5
```

If True

Then we do `replace` or `map`

```
Data['Gender'] = Data['Gender'].map({0:1,1:0})#Data['Gender'].replace({0:1,1:0})
```